# Moments of derivatives of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

As it says in the title - I'm looking for results on
\[ \int _1^T|\zeta ^{(n)}(\sigma +it)|^{2k}dt\]
for general $n\in \mathbb N$.  Are there any?  I only need upper bounds and logarithm factors aren't important.

I'm aware that (at least the lower) moments are worked out using the approximate functional equation and consequently the proofs would go through for derivatives as well, the sums involved only changing by logarithm factors.

Comment: What is $\sigma$? As $t\to \infty$, if $\zeta(\sigma+it)=O(t^{\mu_\sigma})$ then $\zeta(\sigma+it\pm\delta)=O(t^{\mu_\sigma+\epsilon})$ so that $\zeta^{(n)}(\sigma+it)=O(t^{\mu_\sigma+\epsilon})$. Hadamard 3 lines theorem and the functional equation gives the convexity bound for $\mu_\sigma$, the approximate functional equation gives the so called subconvexity bound.

Comment: hmm, i don't think i understood.  a bound for the derivatives follows automatically from a bound for zeta?  what is sigma: it's in [1/2,1) and i guess i want to take it as close to 1/2 as possible

Comment: Sure the Cauchy integral formula gives bounds for all the derivatives at $z_0$ once you know a bound on a small disk around $z_0$. So a $O(t^{\mu_\sigma+\epsilon})$ bound for $\zeta(s)$ on $\Re(s)\in (\sigma-\delta,\sigma+\delta)$ gives a $O(t^{\mu_\sigma+\epsilon})$ bound for $\zeta^{(n)}(s)$ on $\Re(s)=\sigma$.

Comment: perfect, thanks!

Comment: I assume $\sigma = \frac{1}{2}$ here. All other places can be worked out similarly, but this is the critical line. I would assume that one should be able to prove that the integral is $\ll T^{1 + \epsilon}$ for $k \leq 2$ and all $n \geq 0$, but it is not obvious to me that this is possible. One can get $\ll T^{\frac{k}{2} + 1 + \epsilon}$ approximately for free using the convexity bound and Cauchy's integral formula as noted by reuns.

Comment: i wanted $\sigma $ as much to the left of 1 as possible, even if i couldn't reach 1/2.  i think it would be possible, since van der corput summation (which is the proof of the approximate functional equation that i'm familiar with) won't be that affected with $\log $'s i don't think.  anyway, reuns' comment was enough me and i sorted it